# Fastest way to re-open current Xcode project

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

There are times when we work with a project in Xcode and we need to re-open (close and then open) the current project again.

I wonder what is the fastest way to do that? Do we have any keyboard shortcut combination to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the below option turn off

> (Settings->General)

Once it is turned off and you try to open the Xcode it will resume from the same state.

[image]

I Generally keep XCode in the dock section and do a right click on it to see all the recent projects.

If you ask me a way to open fast then you should do spotlight search by **cmd + spacebar** and type your project name.

Comment: Quit and open the whole Xcode? for re-open the current project?

Comment: cmd + spacebar for project with long names are not good option, although it works for other cases

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd + spacebar
```

Opens up the search bar in macOS, just type few letters of your project and hit enter it, this is the fastest i can think of.

Comment: It's good for re-open the Xcode itself, not recent project inside xcode

Comment: double enter opens xCode and latest project,

Comment: and typing the name of ur project opens that project too

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have unchecked "Close windows when quitting app" in System Preferences you can just quit and relaunch Xcode. This will restore the previously opened projects in Xcode.